# logstash convert UTC time to long timestamp

Tags: logstash

i have a request, convert log's time format such as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss  to a long timestamp, but i don't know how to set it in logstash plugin date , anyway suggest will be grateful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Ruby` plugin to do conversion. Here is the sample config

```
input {
        stdin {
        }
}

filter {
        ruby {
                code => "
                        # yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
                        event['parseTime'] = Time.parse(event['message']).to_i

                "
        }
}
output {
  stdout{codec => "rubydebug"}
}
```

Sample Input:

```
2015-11-03 15:00:11
```

Sample Output:

```
{
       "message" => "2015-11-03 15:00:11",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-11-03T08:31:27.419Z",
          "host" => "BEN_LIM",
     "parseTime" => 1446534011
}
```

The `parseTime` field is in Timestamp format.

Comment: finally , if your time need accurate µs , in ruby plugin , you should use  (Time.parse(event['message']).to_f).floor , thank @Ben Lim anwser,

Answer (score 1):

The date{} filter takes two arguments: the field that contains the date string, and another string that specifies the format.  The default output is to overwrite the @timestamp field, which is the default document date used by elasticsearch (and kibana).

By converting it to a date, you get to do all the magic elasticsearch date-type stuff with it (like comparing it to 'now', etc).